# How to change ruby-bundle version?

Tags: ruby

I have to run this command (ubuntu 18.04)

```
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_checklists RAILS_ENV=production
```

But I got an unknown error

```
Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue
```

Before that I got a bundler's version error, where I had to change bundler version from 2.1.4 to 1.3.0-2.0. I installed the 1.3.0 version, but 2.1.4 was a default, and I remove `bundler-2.1.4.gemspec` from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/specifications/default and uninstall 2.1.4.

So `gem list bundler` shows only the 1.3.0 default version. But when I run `/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle -v`, it shows 2.1.4 version.

The question is how can I run bundle-1.3.0 instead of bundle-2.1.4?

Comment: try `bundle _1.3.0_ exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_checklists RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: @NinhLe the same error and also `Gem::GemNotFoundException: can't find gem bundler (= 2.1.4) with executable bundle`

Comment: Did you run it in the project folder?

Comment: can you show your Gemfile.lock, I guess your Gemfile.lock end with ```BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4```

Comment: @Spikie yes, Gemfile has `BUNDLED WITH 2.1.4`. Should I change it to 1.3.0?

Comment: @EvgenyMusonov yep, It will solve your problem

Comment: @Spikie It looks like it works, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
bundle update --bundler
```

This will update the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the version of bundler to execute a command (most often you need an older version of bundler, but don't want to uninstall newer ones):

```
bundle _1.0.10_ -v
```

An example is rails 3.2, which freezes bundler at version ~> 1.0:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile: rails (~> 3.2) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on bundler (~> 1.0)

Current Bundler version: bundler (1.13.6)
```

You can solve this with:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.0.10
bundle _1.0.10_ install
```